# iOS bandpass filter

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, signal-processing, core-audio

I'm developing an iPhone application using the Audio Unit to perform a bandpass filter. The iOS bandpass filter API  needs two parameters: center frequency (in Hz) and bandwidth (in cents with ranges from 100 to 12000). But I do not understand what is cents? How to translate cents into frequency?

For example if I want to perform a filter to pass frequency from 500 to 8000. What center frequency and bandwidth should I use?

Thanks for the help. Any explanation would be really helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Cents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cent_%28music%29) are a logarithmic unit of measure for music intervals. You can find a converter from [Cents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cent_%28music%29) to frequency ratios [here](http://www.sengpielaudio.com/calculator-centsratio.htm). There is also quite a bit of information on google if you search for ***Audio Cents to Frequency***. Hope that Helps!

Comment: Thanks for the link! So, I guess I should choose center frequency 4250Hz and width 4800 cents ...

Comment: Actually I try those values but the result seems to cut off at around 16kHz instead of 8kHz ... Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Play with the numbers to see what gives you the right value. Maybe try 2400 cents? Also, the site I gave you is based 2. Maybe the code you are using is another base, which would change the cents value.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying with various values to figure out the correct one. I'll post again once I confirm it. Many thanks for the link and help!